# matlab gui to load dicom images using a slider

Tags: image, matlab, user-interface

I am trying to create a GUI without using GUIDE to score multiple dicom images in a folder. I need to move through the images in the folder with the slider and then enter a score for each image based on a subjective image quality rubric. I assume I needed the following uicontrols: "pushbutton" to select image folder; "slider" to move between images; and "textbox" to enter a numeric value for score and convert to string to save for each image. However, I am having issues organizing the GUI code and would appreciate assistance considering my limited abilities.

With my code, I was only able to load the images in the folder on one of the image axes(Img1) created. However, I want to be able to use the push button (i.e. @SelectFolderbutton_callback) to select the folder containing the images instead and then have the display strings show inside the "textbox" of the GUI, instead of the command window.

Below is my code:

```
function simplegui_1
% Create figure
clear all
close all hidden
clc

f = figure('Visible','off','Name','simplegui_1',...
    'Position',[520,100,1300,700]);

% Create an axes object 
Img1 = axes('Parent',f,'Units','pixels',...
    'Position',[38 152 512 512]);
Img2 = axes('Parent',f,'Units','pixels',...
    'Position',[750 152 512 512]);

% % create a static text to ask for image folder
hloadimages = uicontrol('Style','text',...
    'String','Load Images','Position',[600 615 100 20],...
    'Callback',{@SelectFolderbutton_callback});

% create a pushbutton to ask for image folder
hSelectFolder = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton',...
    'String','Select Folder','Position',[570 550 150 50],...
    'Callback',{@SelectFolderbutton_callback});

% create text for log files 
htext = uicontrol('Style','text',...
    'Position',[100 18 1070 50],...
    'Callback',{@SelectFolderbutton_callback});

% Create a slider to display the images
slider = uicontrol('Style', 'slider',...
    'Parent', f, 'String', 'Image No.',...
    'Callback', @slider_callback, ...
    'Position', [100 115 350 20]);

set([f,Img1,Img2,hloadimages,hSelectFolder,htext,slider],'Units','normalized');

% Obtain directory or folder containing images 
    myFolder = uigetdir();
% Show error message if folder inexistent
    if ~isdir(myFolder)
        errorMessage = sprintf('Error: The following folder does not exist:\n%s',myFolder);
        uiwait(warndlg(errorMessage));
        return;
    end
    % access image files (DICOM or IMA files)
    filePattern = fullfile(myFolder, '*.dcm');
    dcmFiles = dir(filePattern);
    baseFilenames = {dcmFiles.name};
    numberOfFiles = length(baseFilenames);
    randomOrder = [randperm(numberOfFiles)];

    for k = 1:numberOfFiles
        filenumber = randomOrder(k);
        fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFilenames{filenumber});
        fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', baseFilenames{filenumber});
        imageArray(:,:,k) = dicomread(fullFileName);
        %     imageArray = imcrop(imageArray(:,:,k), [148 146 220 220]);
        %     imageheader(:,:,k) = dicominfo(fullFileName);
        %     b = imageheader(:,:,k).RescaleIntercept;
        %     m = imageheader(:,:,k).RescaleSlope;
        %     imageArray(:,:,k) = imageArray(:,:,k).* m + b;
    end

function SelectFolderbutton_callback(~, eventdata)
% I need the above code to be here to load the images in the directory
% .....    
end

set(f, 'Visible', 'on');
movegui(Img1,'onscreen')% To display application onscreen
movegui(Img1,'center') % To display application in the center of screen

sliderMin = 1;
sliderMax = numberOfFiles; % this is variable
sliderStep = [1, 1]/(sliderMax - sliderMin); % major and minor steps of 1

set(slider, 'Min', sliderMin);
set(slider, 'Max', sliderMax);
set(slider, 'SliderStep', sliderStep);
set(slider, 'Value', sliderMin); % set to beginning of sequence
%% Beginning of slider callback function
function slider_callback(source, eventdata)
    sliderMin = get(source, 'Min');
    sliderMax = get(source, 'Max') ;
    sliderStep = get(source, 'SliderStep'); 
    currentSlice = get(source, 'Value');
    axes(Img1); 
    imagesc(imageArray(:,:,currentSlice), [1000 1150]);
    colormap(gray); axis image; impixelinfo;
    disp(['Slider moved to ' num2str(currentSlice)]);
    %[X, Y, newArray, RECT] = imcrop(Img);
end % end of slider callback

end % end of GUI function
```

Comment: There is a code on File Exchange that does that: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40753-imtool3d

Comment: @Jigg Thanks for the info. However, the imtool3D code is an advanced tool that moves through images and does not really solve my problem of writing my own callback for loading the dicom images.

Comment: I didn't imply it did. I just figured you might be interested. You could compare your version to his, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Jigg, it's a pretty robust tool.